# Magento 2: Product's Layered Navigation Filter DIsplay Type API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, layered-navigation, category-listing

I am working on Rest API.
I want a product filter type (checkbox, multiple selections,yes/no) so that mobile filters can be shown based on that.

For example on website filters showing like this :

[image]

How can we decide for Mobile App to show in same manner ?

I am using API : **V1/categoryfilter?category_id=4**

Comment: Do you want product filter type only OR you are looking filter data options?

Comment: filter data type.